# Proper way to add forgeign keys in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

So - I've been learning rails for the last 4 months and would like to think that I have a pretty good overview of it. Albeit, there are a few gray areas that I would like to make clearer. One being databases, and foreign keys in particular.

Lets say I have a Products table and a Sales table, and I'd like the listed sales to be a subset of the listed products. In other-words the sales are related to the products. Presumably I could do this by using a foreign key, however, I'm not sure the correct way to write this.

My guess is on the Sales migration I would add something like: add_index :products ?

And then of course use associations in the model?

Would that be the right way of doing it?

Please help clear this up.

Comment: what you want is easily acheived through [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) but it's not done with index but with a `foreign key` you will have to reference the product table in the sales table `tablename.refrences :products`

Answer (score 1):

You would run the following migration

```
change_table :sales do |t| 
   t.references product 
end
```

This should add `product_id` into your sales table. Having done this you need to `run rake db:migrate` to make your database migrate these changes.

Also take a look at: [Ruby On Rails - Changing tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables)

Comment: "The `references` helper does not actually create foreign key constraints for you. You will need to use `execute` or a plugin that adds foreign key support."

Comment: @muistooshort okay in that case could you not just do `rails g migration add_product_id_to_sales_product_id:integer`

Comment: No, that still won't create a [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-fk.html) in the database because Rails doesn't believe in real [foreign keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) or any other sort of reliable data integrity mechanisms. If you actually care about your data and want to be able to trust it, you have to set up your FKs and CHECKs by hand through SQL.

Comment: @muistooshort Well, I mean if we are talking about in the context of the actual database then yes you are correct. But from what TonyP was asking I believe he was referring to adding a relation between the two models.